# Where to Start developing XBox One Game having Kinect Capabilties

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, xbox-one

I need to develop a XBox One game having Kinect capabilities. Could anyone please suggest me from where should i start it?

Moreover, i gone through with some forums they suggest go with XBox One XDK but Unity is the first choice for game developers.

So which is better : XBox One XDK or Unity (both supporting kinect)

Also, can i write code in Visual studio for both or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> So which is better : XBox One XDK or Unity

Apples and Oranges. Unity actually requires the XDK anyway. See below.

[Unity3D Multiplatform](https://unity3d.com/unity/multiplatform) and more importantly Microsoft's ID@XBox for XBox One, allow you to target XBox One [for free](http://www.xbox.com/en-us/Developers/id) and *[get access to two developer kits at no cost](http://www.xbox.com/en-us/Developers/id)*.

> Joining the programme gets you access to a wealth of documentation, recorded talks, development samples and the official forums, so if you ever run into any problems during development, there are many avenues you can take to get a helping hand. You will also receive a free Unity license for Xbox One, as well as two free development kits to kickstart the development process.  [Tell me more](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/developers/articles/week03jul14/the-facts-behind-id-xbox-chris-charla-talks-at-develop-conference-2014/)

The XDK is obtained from Microsoft regardless of whether you use Unity. However, Unity requires that you have the XDK in the first place if your intention is to target XBO.

> Also, can i write code in Visual studio for both or not?

Yes you can.  In fact, Unity can be used with Visual Studio even prior to XBO development with UnityVS, once an indie tool, now taken over by Microsoft and is available from the VS Extensions Gallery.

Comment: Thanks Micky! It'll really help me. 
Furthermore: do you have any idea about "What will be the process for beat testing & How can i allow user to test at his XBox console?" Also, "What data format XDK will return, and how to manage players data on Database?"
At this stage I need to select the best platform for Game development and with ease on development and deployment.

Comment: They're fine questions that you should post as _new questions_.  However, follow the XDK links

Comment: You're quite welcome.  Maybe a upvote and accept if you like this answer. Thanks :)